# FacebookRedirectLoginHelper reset authorization code?

Tags: php, facebook, authorization, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to delete scheduled posts from different Facebook pages owned by the same account.
However I get this error :

```
This authorization code has been used.
```

Therefore I tried putting this in a loop, so that a new code generates, in vain.

```
foreach($events as $event){
        $fbhelper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper("/events/delete/$id");
        $nodeid = $event->fbid;
        $session = $fbhelper->getSessionFromRedirect();
        if ($session){
            try {
                $request = new FacebookRequest(
                    $session,
                      'DELETE',
                      '/'.$nodeid
                );
                $response = $request->execute();
            } catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
                // 
            } catch(\Exception $ex) {
                //
            }           
        }$session = '';
        }
```

But I still get the error, so I am missing something.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: _“Therefore I tried putting this in a loop, so that a new code generates, in vain”_ - that’s because the code is not generated there at all. The code is a result of your sending the user through the login flow - that happens on Facebook’s side. You need to exchange that code for an access token once, and only once.

Comment: thanks for the informations, good to know :-) now I must find out why it is not actually deleting my scheduled posts

Comment: Deleting page posts requires the use of a page access token; so if you want this to work for multiple pages the user has admin access to, you will still need to specify the “matching” page access token for every single request. Btw., looks like you are using the outdated PHP SDK v4 there, current is v5 (and that does not use a Session object any more) - I would recommend that you switch to the v5, if you are developing this from scratch here.

Comment: Sadly this isn't something from scratch, I can't tell where to change the SDK. I get what you're saying on the access tokens. I cannot seem to see the token called in the delete function at all, or is it because it is not needed for a single page ?

Comment: No, you need a page access token to delete posts from a page in any case. I am not sure if FacebookRequest in the PHP SDK v4 allows to just pass the access token as an additional parameter under the name `access_token`, or whether that will be overwritten by what the session object contains. And you will still need to find a way to figure out which page the post belongs to in the first place, so that you can specify the corresponding page token.

Comment: Seems you're right, sessions contains the token, I need to upgraded then

Comment: Not necessarily; if you have an access token, you can easily _create_ a session object from it, see example under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookSession/4.0.0

Comment: Interesting ! I don't understand how they actually retrieve that access token though..

Comment: You need `manage_pages` permission from the user, and then request `/me/accounts` - that will give you all the pages they have admin access to, and corresponding page access tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably you'd want to move

```
$fbhelper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper("/events/delete/$id");
$session = $fbhelper->getSessionFromRedirect();
```

to outside of the loop

Comment: Thanks , fixes this but my scheduled post is not deleting, guess I've more to figure out :-)